# hibernate narrow down lazy loaded collection

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Car {
    private Integer id;
    private List<CarOrder> carOrders;
}

public class CarOrder {
    private Car car;
    private Long endDate;
    private Long id;
}
```

and hibernate mapping

```
<class entity-name="car" name="test.es.Car" table="CARS" schema="ARK_ES">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">ES_SEQUENCE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <bag name="carOrders" inverse="true" lazy="true">
            <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <key column="CAR_ID"/>
            <one-to-many not-found="ignore" entity-name="carOrder"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
    <class entity-name="carOrder" name="temp.es.CarOrder" table="CAR_ORDERS" schema="ARK_ES">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">ES_ORDER_SEQUENCE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="endDate" column="END_DATE"/>
        <many-to-one name="car" entity-name="car">
            <column name="CAR_ID"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
```

I need to load all cars and car orders with endDate greater than some value. Also i need to cache the query for car order. i tried to use hibernate filters, but they are not cached. Is it possible to achieve this using hibernate api without custom queries?
I forgot to mention that car can have no orders, but it must be in result.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a well defined question to your post.

Comment: i added a question. Please tell me what do you mean, if it is not enough.

Comment: Much better now. Thank you!

Comment: If the end day you're going to use is static, for example last two month orders, you can achieve it using a where condition. Otherwise, you'll need to create your custom query.

Comment: How can i add a where condition to lasy loading collection? If i do not use filters the full table is loaded.

Comment: Without a query/criteria you can't do what you want because you are binding a runtime parameter (endDate); the only way could be a @Where annotation on collection but only accepts static SQL and don't accept dynamic code and can't be a solution. If with Hibernate API do you mean Criteria/HQL?

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the @fitler and @filterdef annotation on your collection class. But then it is very important to enable the filters in the session. Please follow this link on how to enable filters, they are not enabled by default.
[How to enable hibernate filter for sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680750/how-to-enable-hibernate-filter-for-sessionfactory-getcurrentsession)

Comment: Yes, i've already tried filters and they work fine. The problem is that the results of the filtering are not cached, and each time i iterate over collection, i get new query to database.

Comment: did you enable the query level cache ?