# Restrict mapping to get a specific one-to-one relationship for JPA-based sorting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

### Situation

I have two Hibernate entities, `Document` and `TitleTranslation`, with a one-to-many relationship, as there are multiple titles for a document, one for each language.
`Document` has a property `id` and `TitleTranslation` references that through `document_id`.

Therefore, to connect titles to documents, the natural solution would be a field as follows:

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
List<TitleTranslation> translations;
```

### Goal

For sorting, I'm currently passing a `Sort` object to a JPA repository, e.g. `repository.findAll(mySort)`.
The sort order property may reference transitive properties, such as `owner.firstname` (document has owner, owner has firstname).

This works well as long as transitive properties are joined in a one-to-one fashion, but breaks down for one-to-many relationships as above:
I'd like to sort by a document's title, but there's just a list of translations.
However, since I'm just interested in one specific language, there is just one title in the list relevant to me, therefore a de-facto one-to-one relationship.

**How can I achieve a one-to-one mapping to a translation of a certain language, so I could sort by e.g. `translationEn.title`?**

### Partial solution

As it turns out, mapping through `OneToOne` results in one of the translations being picked (the first one?):

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "document")
TitleTranslation translation;
```

This relies on a corresponding mapping in `TitleTranslation`:

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Document document;
```

Now, I would like to indicate on the `translation` property that only translations with `language='en'` should be joined.
I tried to use the `Where` annotation, but this only works in connection with one-to-many relationships.
Thus, the following doesn't work as expected:

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "document")
@Where(clause = "language='en'")
TitleTranslation translation;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using filters:

**1)** Define the filter:

```
@FilterDef(name = "enFilter"
                , defaultCondition=" language='en'")
public class TitleTranslation {
```

**2)** Use the filter:

```
@ManyToOne(mappedBy = "document")
@Filter(name = "enFilter")
TitleTranslation translation;
```

You may need to define a `@ManyToOne` instead of `@OneToOne` though.

**3)** In transactional method:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.enableFilter("enFilter");
```

Comment: Actually, I've tried something similar. The problem is that I'm using JPA and do the request in the fashion of `repository.findAll(sort)`, so I don't have a session reference. Or is there a way to always enable that filter by default?

Comment: There is no straightforward way. This is bit of a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855260/global-hibernate-filter-on-all-database-queries

Comment: Okay, I got it to work with JPA by getting the session first, from an injected `ObjectFactory<EntityManager>` as follows: `emProvider.getObject().unwrap(Session.class)`. Maybe you can add this to the answer, then I'll accept it. For what it's worth, I'm now using multiple filters, one per language, and selectively activating them before a JPA call.