# Hibernate exclude rows with condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {

    some attributes

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private EnumObject status;
}
```

My Enum:

```
public enum EnumObject {
    OK,
    BAD,
    SOME_CASE,
    ANOTHER_CASE;
```

There are a possibility to say never return Entity when `status=BAD` for all queries

Comment: Not automatically to my knowledge, for such a scenario, your query will need to exclude based entity.status != "BAD"

Comment: @SMA i want to exclude for any query

Answer (score 2):

Kindly see if the below notions help you in achieving what you are after:

**2.3.21. @Where**

> Sometimes, you want to filter out entities or collections using custom
> SQL criteria. This can be achieved using the @Where annotation, which
> can be applied to entities and collections.

Example 78. @Where mapping usage

```
public enum AccountType {
    DEBIT,
    CREDIT
}

@Entity(name = "Client")
public static class Client {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Where( clause = "account_type = 'DEBIT'")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Account> debitAccounts = new ArrayList<>( );

    @Where( clause = "account_type = 'CREDIT'")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Account> creditAccounts = new ArrayList<>( );

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity

}
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-where

**2.3.23. @Filter**

> The @Filter annotation is another way to filter out entities or
> collections using custom SQL criteria. Unlike the @Where annotation,
> @Filter allows you to parameterize the filter clause at runtime.
>
> Now, considering we have the following Account entity:

Example 85. @Filter mapping entity-level usage

```
@Entity(name = "Account")
@FilterDef(
    name="activeAccount",
    parameters = @ParamDef(
        name="active",
        type="boolean"
    )
)
@Filter(
    name="activeAccount",
    condition="active_status = :active"
)
public static class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Client client;

    @Column(name = "account_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountType type;

    private Double amount;

    private Double rate;

    @Column(name = "active_status")
    private boolean active;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-filter

---

Also take a look at [Global hibernate filter on all database queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855260/global-hibernate-filter-on-all-database-queries)  which uses AspectJ to intercept the queries if you want to do it in another way.