# Spring JPA + Hibernate Add Where condition to my entire model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-security, spring-data

I'm currently working on a new project and we are working with Spring DATA over Hibernate.

So the thing is that our base model has 3 fields "`IsActive`" "`IsDeleted`" and "`AccessLevel`"
The idea behind these is that a any record could be deactivated and logically deleted.
I Think I could write `@Where` annotation over my Base class and write the clause there `IsActive=true AND IsDeleted=false`

But the access level is in the authenticated user, so all the records in the DB inherit the field access level and it is a int, so records with Access Level 0 are public, and people with access level 1 can find records with level 1 and 0 but not level 2.

is there any way to implement this in my baseModel or in my CustomBaseRepository?

Answer (score 0):

For the access restriction, you might want to have a look at hibernate filters :
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html

The hibernate documentation shows how to activate a filter on a session, but not how to make it always active.

As it seems you want to achieve that, have a look at this question : [How to enable hibernate filter for sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680750/how-to-enable-hibernate-filter-for-sessionfactory-getcurrentsession)

The answer provided there : enabling the filter with aop on the hibernate openSession method, should work well with spring-data too.